# Solr: Retrieve field names from a solr index?

Tags: solr

How can I query a Solr instance for all (or prefixed) field names?

I want to use dynamic fields where I do not know how many may exist e.g: `category_0_s`, `category_1_s` etc.

Preferably I'd like to use a prefix e.g. `category_`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the luke handler:

```
http://solr:8983/solr/admin/luke?numTerms=0
```

Use a xpath to get all the field which has the tag dynamicBase matching the dynamic fields definition you are looking for.

Comment: @Philippe That won't get the names of all the dynamic fields in use, which is what the original poster asked for.  Read the question and answer carefully.

Comment: @GoalBased Ok, but if instead of criticizing you gave a better solution, that would help as well. So to update my "answer", the correct call for dynamic fields is http://host:<port>/solr/collection/schema/dynamicfields. For more options see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API

Comment: I posted an answer below that doesn't require Luke

Comment: How would I get a list of all fields using this term, and still apply fq on the same?

Answer (score 51):

This query will return a comma-separated list of all the fields that are in use, including dynamic ones.

```
select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet
```

To answer the original question, this is how to get a list of all the fields starting with category_

```
select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet&fl=category_*
```

The presence of the `facet` parameter is needed to make this query work on newer versions of Solr.  On older versions, it will work without it.

On older versions, a wildcard in the `fl` parameter won't work.

Comment: In Solr5, including both `facet` and `facet.field` causes a 400 Bad Request, but still include the fields.  Leaving out `facet.field` returns the fields and a 200 Success

Comment: @Izkata Thanks for the improvement!  I've updated my answer.  Curiously, setting `facet=true` doesn't work, but `facet` with no value works.

Comment: On Solr 6.3 only fl=id,category... worked without the facet=on. I am wondering if i still need to add something in the schema to show addition info

Comment: Bizarre, why does this only work with csv as return format? Why can't I get this as JSON? (Solr newb here)

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye  because JSON has no column titles.  By asking for 0 rows this returns the CSV column titles only.  It's evil genius.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this from your Java application you can use [Solrj](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) and [LukeRequestRequestHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler).

Your code would look like this.

```java
LukeRequest lukeRequest = new LukeRequest();
lukeRequest.setNumTerms(0);

LukeResponse lukeResponse = lukeRequest.process(server);

Map<String, FieldInfo> fieldInfoMap = lukeResponse.getFieldInfo();

for (Entry<String, FieldInfo> entry : fieldInfoMap.entrySet()) {

    String fieldName = entry.getKey();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = entry.getValue();

    // process fieldInfo    
}
```

Comment: Where does `facet` come from?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed the code to efficiently iterate through the hashmap entries. Hope this helps.