# Solr: where to find the Luke request handler

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm trying to get a list of all the fields, both static and dynamic, in my Solr index.  [Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296974/765287) suggested using the Luke Request Handler for this.

It suggests finding the handler at this url:

```
http://solr:8983/solr/admin/luke?numTerms=0
```

When I try this url on my server, however, I get a 404 error.

The admin page for my core is here `http://solr:8983/solr/#/mycore`, so I also tried `http://solr:8983/solr/#/mycore/admin/luke`. This also gave me another 404.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Which url should I be using?

Comment: Have you enabled the luke request handler in your solrconfig.xml as described?

Comment: Yes. I've added the following as the last line in my solrconfig.xml: `<requestHandler name="/admin/luke" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />`

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to enable the Luke Request Handler. Note that if you started from the example solrconfig.xml you probably don't need to enable it explicitly because

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
```

does it for you.

Then if you need to access the data programmatically you have to make an HTTP GET request to `http://solr:8983/solr/mycore/admin/luke` (no hash mark!). The response is in XML but specifying wt parameter you can obtain different formats (e.g. `http://solr:8983/solr/mycore/admin/luke?wt=json`)

If you only want to see fields in SOLR web interface select your core from the drop down menu and then click on "Schema Browser"

Answer (score 2):

In Solr 6, the solr.admin.AdminHandlers has been removed.  If your solrconfig.xml has the line `<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />`, it will fail to load.  You will see errors in the log telling you it failed to load the class `org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers`.

You must include in your solrconfig.xml the line,

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/luke" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />
```

but the URL is core-specific, i.e. http://your_server.com:8983/solr/your_core_name/admin/luke

And you can specify the parameters **fl,numTerms,id,docId** as follows:

- /admin/luke
- /admin/luke?fl=cat
- /admin/luke?fl=id&numTerms=50
- /admin/luke?id=SOLR1000
- /admin/luke?docId=2

Comment: How to reload this `solrconfig.xml` file after changing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this Luke tool](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases) which allows you to explore Lucene index.

You can also use the solr admin page : 
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core/schema-browser