# Is there a way to view search document fields that are only indexed but not stored via the solr admin panel using the query tool?

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to view the indexed but not stored fields of a solr search document in the solr admin query tool, is there any provision for this?

Example Field Configuration:

```
<field name="product_data" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" docValues="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using schema version 1.6, Solr will automagically fetch the values from the stored docValues, even if the field itself is set as `stored="false"`. Include the field name in `fl` to get the values.

However, even if you're looking for the actual tokens indexed for a document / field / value, using the Analysis page is usually the preferred way as it allows you to tweak the value and see the response quickly. The [Luke Request Handler / Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889405/137650) is useful if you want to explore the actual indexed tokens.