# Solr schema, how to get dynamic fields in a collection

Tags: solr

I'm running Solr 4.10.3.

setting dynamic fields of the type *_f

I would like to list all the added dynamic fields, but am not having luck using  /schema/dynamicfields, or /schema/fields routes.

I see that the schema-browser in the web-app dashboard is capable of listing them and would like to know how that is done, anyone have a clue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211139/solr-retrieve-field-names-from-a-solr-index

Comment: question 3211139 recommends using the luke handler, which is rolled into the admin handler, but I can't find documentation for it or guess how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This query

```
select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet&fl=*_f
```

will get you all the dynamic fields ending with _f that are currently in use.

Comment: It looks like this returns an HTTP 400 though. I think you're breaking something which makes it spew all the headers (it also doesn't work with any kind of filter; i.e. it doesn't respect said filter with either `q` or `fq`)