# How do I query (via url) the solr.admin.LukeRequestHandler to get collection index data

Tags: solr4

I want to use the luke handler as suggested in [Solr schema, how to get dynamic fields in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239719/solr-schema-how-to-get-dynamic-fields-in-a-collection), which is http://solr:8983/solr/admin/luke?numTerms=0

but the 4.10.3 solrconfig.xml has the following entry which indicates luke has been rolled into /admin/ and I should be able to use the http://localhost:8983/solr/admin path, which give me a 404 error.

```
  <requestHandler name="/admin/"
                  class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
  <!-- This single handler is equivalent to the following... -->
  <!--
     <requestHandler name="/admin/luke"       class="solr.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />
     <requestHandler name="/admin/system"     class="solr.admin.SystemInfoHandler" />
     <requestHandler name="/admin/plugins"    class="solr.admin.PluginInfoHandler" />
     <requestHandler name="/admin/threads"    class="solr.admin.ThreadDumpHandler" />
     <requestHandler name="/admin/properties" class="solr.admin.PropertiesRequestHandler" />
     <requestHandler name="/admin/file"       class="solr.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler" >
    -->
```

When I look for LukeRequestHandler documentation I find http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/LukeRequestHandler.html which expects I am building a java app, which I am not.

I attempt to use several methods found there in a url, all of which 404.

In addition to "how do I query the luke handler to get index data", 
 "is this the correct documentation for what I am trying to figure out?".

Any help in understanding how (these) java docs relate to me trying to understand how Solr works from url would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent some days scratching my head with the same issue. Apparently, you need to include the name of your core into every request.

Testing with the "gettingstarted" core:

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke/ gives 404.

http://localhost:8983/solr/**gettingstarted**/admin/luke/ gives an XML with the information of the index.

Check if this solves your problem.