# How to get all solr field names after filter is applied?

Tags: solr

There is an answer how I can get all solr fields names with curl
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546298/5165781

So, do get all fields names I do
`select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet`

But how can I get fields names after I apply a filter?

For example:

if I want all solr fields names for specific date, I try : `select?q=*:*&fq="dt":"2016-10-06T00:00:00Z"&wt=csv&rows=0&facet`

But it returns all field names across all documents.

So, how can I retrieve fields names with specific filters?

Comment: Use fl parameter. `/select?q=*:*&fq="dt":"2016-10-06T00:00:00Z"&fl=*`

Comment: I do `/select?q=*:*&fq="dt":"2016-10-06T00:00:00Z"&fl=*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet` and still get names all names across all days